# Conditional "ref" in SPRING beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If I have something like

```
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.askQuestion.HelloWorld">
       <property name="message" ref = (postCard or formalLetter )if something />
   </bean>
```

...

```
 <bean for postCard class />
  <bean for formalLetter class />
```

And in class HelloWorld the message is an Interface like this:

```
MessageInterface message ; // also get; set are here
```

And there are Two classes - `class postCard implements MessageInterface`  and `class formalLetter implements MessageInterface`
And a property `message` in class `HelloWorld` must be initialized with an 
postCard bean or with a formalLetter if some  value in some class (say com.askQuestion.ClassWithAConditional ) has for example `true` value?

so if - `com.askQuestion.ClassWithAConditional.SendFormalLetter == true;`
then

```
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.askQuestion.HelloWorld">
           <property name="message" ref = "formalLetterId" />
       </bean>
```

and if  `com.askQuestion.ClassWithAConditional.SendFormalLetter == false;`
then

```
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.askQuestion.HelloWorld">
               <property name="message" ref = "postCardId" />
           </bean>
```

Comment: Use spring profiles or use a factory bean which creates/returns the instance needed.

Comment: give a sample of a factory bean for this case please/ Is the logic in XML or in code?

Comment: What is it you don't understand? Create a bean implementing `FactoryBean` which has a reference to both beans and depending on your condition returns the one you need.

Comment: I am new in spring - I have listened to a lection and I have a question - I have not heard about factory bean pattern - so I need an easy sample. Perhaps you could provide a reference for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you have 2 options.

1. Use Spring Profiles to load one of the beans based on an active profile
2. Use a `FactoryBean` to switch between the different implementations.

### Profiles

When using Spring you can use profiles. In xml declare a nested `beans` element and set which `profile` it should be active in. The active profile can be set by setting the `spring.profiles.active` property.

```
<beans ...>
    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.askQuestion.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" ref="messageBean" />
    </bean>    

    <beans profile="postcard">
        <bean id="messageBean" class="PostcardBean" />
    <beans>
    <beans profile="letter">
        <bean id="messageBean" class="LetterBean" />
    </beans>
</beans>
```

More information on profiles is in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-xml).

### FactoryBean

You could also define a [`FactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) which selects the correct bean to use based on your condition.

```
public class MessageFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<MessageInterface> {

    private MessageInterface postcard;
    private MessageInterface letter;

    public MessageInterface getObject() {
        if (your condition here) {
            return letter;
        }
        return postcard;
    }
    // other methods omitted
}

<beans ...>
    <bean id="messageBean" class="MessageFactoryBean">
        <property name="postcard">
            <bean class="PostcardBean" />
        </property>
        // other properties omitted
    </bean>

    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.askQuestion.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" ref="messageBean"/>
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

More information about `FactoryBean`s in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-factorybean).

Answer (score 2):

You can use FactoryBean something like this

```
public class MyFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<MessageInterface>{
  private boolean condition; 

  public void setCondition(boolean condition){ this.condition =condition ; }

  public MessageInterface getObject(){ 
    if(condition){return new PostCard();}
    else{return new formalLetter();}
  }

  public Class<MessageInterface> getObjectType() { return MessageInterface.class ; } 

  public boolean isSingleton() { return false; }
}
```

Then in your configuration

```
<bean class = "MyFactoryBean" id = "myFactoryBean">
    <property name = "condition" value ="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.askQuestion.HelloWorld">
       <property name="message" ref = "myFactoryBean" />
   </bean>
```

Comment: Why I need this two strings of code - public Class<MessageInterface> getObjectType() { return MessageInterface.class ; } 

  public boolean isSingleton() { return false; } ???

Comment: Those methods are in the inteface FactoryBean, you can see an example here https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean